# Find the splitting field of $x^2 - \pi^4$ over $Q(\pi^4)$

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field, transcendental-numbers

This is the first time I encountered a problem asking to find the splitting field of a polynomial with transcendental coefficients over $Q$ adjoined to a transcendental number over $Q$. I have no idea how to proceed. I know that the elements of $Q(\pi^4)$ are of the form $\frac{f(\pi^4)}{g(\pi^4)}$ where $f,g \in Q[x], g \neq 0.$

Moreover, is there a general way of finding the splitting fields of polynomials with transcendental elements? Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: The easy general way, if you can make it work: Factor the polynomial (in $\Bbb R[x]$) and see what you need to add to $\Bbb Q(\pi^4)$ to make the factors exist.

Comment: I tried factoring it into linear polynomials over $R$ and got $ \pm \pi^2$. so $Q(\pi^4, \pi^2)$

Comment: (Or, more correctly, factor it in $\Bbb C[x]$.)

Comment: But i'm unsure of that since i saw stuff like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432351/what-is-the-splitting-field-of-x3-pi

Comment: Looks good to me. Note that $\pi^4\in\Bbb Q(\pi^2)$, so there is no need for $\pi^4$ in $\Bbb Q(\pi^4,\pi^2)$.

Comment: If you can make all the factors exist, you're done. If you need primitive cube roots of unity to make that happen, like in that post, then you need primitive cube roots of unity. In your case, you don't need them.

Comment: Can you further elaborate why i don't need primitive roots of unity?

Comment: The roots of unity that you need are the square roots of $1$. These are $\pm1$, which are already in the field.

Comment: You also need to argue why it doesn't split already in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^4)$. Note that if that were the case, then we would have $\frac{f(\pi^4)}{g(\pi^4)}=\pi^2$, which implies that $f(\pi^4)-\pi^2g(\pi^4)=0$. Since $\pi$ is transcendental, this implies that $p(x)=f(x^4)-x^2g(x^4)$ is the zero polynomial. Since $f(x^4)$ has all terms of degree multiples of $4$ and $x^2g(x^4)$ with degrees leaving remainder $2$ after division by $4$, this can only happen if $f$ and $g$ are the zero polynomial. However, $g$ is not the zero polynomial.

Comment: @plop You only need to argue that if you're asked to prove that $\Bbb Q(\pi^4)\neq \Bbb Q(\pi^2)$, or equivalently, that the splitting field is a proper extension. The splitting field of $x^2-4$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt4)$. Which looks ridiculous, but not really incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can factorise over $\mathbb{R} $ as $(x-\pi ^2) (x+\pi ^2). $
So you only need to adjoin $\pi ^2 $ so the splitting field is $ \mathbb{Q} (\pi ^4, \pi ^2)= \mathbb{Q}(\pi ^2)$.